# How can I trigger the autocmd FileType commands for all buffers?

Tags: autocmd

I have a key binding to reload my `~/.vimrc`. However, some of my options set via `autocmd FileType` are not active after reloading the config. Those are to set the text width, creating highlights, etc. I can trigger them manually by `set syntax=python`. Is there a way to trigger them again to all open buffers with the correct filetypes?